# Debian runs only under root without xorg

Tags: debian, xorg, grub2, root, journalctl

Nothing foretold any trouble, but my system completely crashed after formatting a neighboring partition (with Windows) and installing new Windows on it.

**The main things I did were**

- Formatted the adjacent partition and installed Windows on it
- because GRUB was overwritten by Windows: I restored it via Live Disk with Linux Mint 21 (and builtin grub recovery tool)

**When I start the system - it**

- doesn't load xorg
- It doesn't let me select the user and I have to enter the root password only.
- I can run `startx` but I can't change the user in this environment
- The Network Manager doesn't work (I tried to run it from the terminal but it just doesn't work), Pulseaudio, Firefox doesn't work correctly (in fact, it can't be used and it just starts up)
- The system suggests "default" mode by exit (Ctrl+D), but when I choose this way, it takes me back to the root password.

**journalctl log:**

```bash
root@noname:~# journalctl -xb
-- Journal begins at Wed 2022-12-07 19:39:55 EST, ends at Sun 2022-12-18 21:54:>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: Linux version 5.10.0-18-amd64 (debian-kernel@lis>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-18>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000000000>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f800-0x00000000000>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e7000-0x00000000000>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000c7f>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c7fb0000-0x00000000c7f>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c7fc0000-0x00000000c7f>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000c7ff0000-0x00000000c7f>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fff00000-0x00000000fff>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000002b7f>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: SMBIOS 2.5 present.
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: DMI: To Be Filled By O.E.M. To Be Filled By O.E.>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: tsc: Detected 3493.538 MHz processor
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable >
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: AGP: No AGP bridge found
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: last_pfn = 0x2b8000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
lines 1-23...skipping...
-- Journal begins at Wed 2022-12-07 19:39:55 EST, ends at Sun 2022-12-18 21:54:45 EST. --
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: Linux version 5.10.0-18-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP>
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-18-amd64 root=UUID=fda4eeeb-ac1f-4ad1-89b3-21a818d77f23 ro quiet
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Dec 18 21:47:40 noname kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
```

**[===> Logfile continued here... <===](https://pastebin.com/JYqzZxWH)**

Comment: did you per chance install the proprietary nvidia driver? The system tries to load the foss, but less-than-perfect nouveau driver, and fails. That's usually a sign of something being wrong with the hardware, or with the combination of the modules you have and the kernel you're booting

Comment: @MarcusMüller I tried to install the driver but an error occurred and I rolled back to nouveau. But I had no problems with the system before reinstalling Windows. Also I have no problem with resolution after startx (as proof of working nouveau driver)

Comment: the logs say nouveau fails to work!